# Why do rgeos/sp and terra give different values for polygon area?

Tags: r, r-sp, terra

I am converting several functions from the `sp` package to `terra` and I have encountered an inconsistency in the calculated area of polygons. The code sample below demonstrates my issue.

```
x = seq(0, 2 * pi, length.out = 100)
circle = cbind(sin(x), cos(x))

# sp/rgeos version
poly.1 = sp::SpatialPolygons(list(sp::Polygons( list(sp::Polygon(circle) ), "circle")))
area.1 = rgeos::gArea(poly.1)

# terra version
poly.2 = terra::vect(circle, type = "polygons", crs = "local")
area.2 = terra::expanse(poly.2, transform = F)

area.1 - area.2 # != 0
```

I have understood that `poly.1` and `poly.2` should be describing the same polygon. The area calculations for each are not the same though (similar, but different enough to break compatibility with existing code).

Can anyone piont out whether I am doing something wrong? Or is there an approach that could get `terra` to deliver the same value as `area.1`?

Comment: are you sure the CRS is identical between terra and sp?

Comment: mirroring the CRS doesn't change anything, so ignore comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two values is -2.479456e-09. That is minuscule, and probably due to floating point imprecision. I would not say that the results are *similar*; they are essentially *the same*.

To get the same results, you can round the area to 6 (or in this case 8) decimals.

```
round(area.1, 6) == round(area.2, 6)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: After some testing (and familiarising myself with the terra package), it appears that all my differences are indeed on the scale of floating point precision.